# Load image from a Buffer/Blob

Tags: javascript, typescript, buffer, blob, electron

I am trying to take an image from the clipboard within electron, and put it on a canvas.

In the electron main process, I have this function which is triggered by a menu item. If I write `img.toBitmap().toString()` to the console it outputs the image data, so I know that there is an image there.

```
export function pasteImage() {
  let img = clipboard.readImage()
  console.log('send paste message')
  mainWindow.webContents.send('paste-image', img.toBitmap())
}
```

Next I have this method which takes the buffer and converts it to a blob. It then should load it into the image and draw the image to the canvas.

```
public pasteImage(image: Buffer, x: number = 0, y: number = 0) {
  let blob = new Blob([image], { type: 'image/bmp' })
  let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  let img = new Image
  img.addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log('loaded image')
    this.ctx.drawImage(img, x, y)
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
  })
  img.src = url
}

ipcRenderer.addListener('paste-image', (e: EventEmitter, img: Buffer) => {
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  let layer = new layer(canvas)
  layer.pasteImage(img)
})
```

The issue I am having is that the load event never gets triggered, however the method `pasteImage(image, x, y)` is executing.

Comment: I don't know electron, but what is exactly in the Buffer returned by `toBitmap`? Fast reading the docs seems to imply that it's the *raw bitmap pixel data*, I guess in some sort of Uint8Array, representing all 4 RGBA channels, but anyway, not a bmp file data, hence not passeable directly to `Blob` constructor. I guess you want either the `toPNG` or `toJPEG` methods.

Comment: @Kaiido Looks like you are correct. In that sense, couldn't I just write the data to the canvas instead of loading an image... `ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(image), 600, 750)` where `image` is the buffer data

Comment: yes probably, but once again I don't know electron nor their nativeImage API.